# Is there a standard type to do "accurate division" in Go?

Tags: go, arithmetic-expressions

I would like to do some "accurate division" in go. Is there a standard type for that?

For example, I would like to store the value "1/3" and "2/3" and be able to add them.

I can define my own type like this:

```
type MyType struct {
    Numerator   int
    Denominator int
}
```

and define functions like:

```
func (a MyType) Plus(b MyType) MyType {
    d := a.Denominator * b.Denominator
    n := (a.Numerator * b.Denominator) + (b.Numerator * a.Denominator)

    return MyType{Numerator: n, Denominator: d}
}
```

but there is probably a more elegant way to do this or a "standard type" that already does that.

Comment: You can use one of the third-party packages if `math/big` does not suit your needs. There  are packages for rational numbers, and there are packages for decimal numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason [`big.Rat`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Rat) in std library doesn't work for your needs? Otherwise asking for package recommendations is off topic ([ask])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know about `big.Rat`. This is all I need! Thank you for your help